# Call a function on a dynamically loaded component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `MainComponent` with a `<router-outlet>` in which child components are loaded.
On the `/messages`-url the `messagesComponent` is loaded. I have added an evenlistener on the `MainComponent` which fires when the user scrolls in the container in which the `<router-outlet>` resides like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "main-component",
    template: `
        <div (scroll)="onContainerScrollEvent($event)">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
`
})
export class MainComponent {
    private messagePage: number = 0;

    onContainerScrollEvent(event: any) {
        this.messagePage += 1;
    }
}
```

When the `onContainerScrollEvent` fires I want to call a function on the `messagesComponent` to get some new messages.
I have added an EventEmitter on the `messagesComponent` which fires on the `onInit` and which passes itself to the parent event, but `<router-outlet>` doesn't support that.

**UPDATE**
Below the answer to my question incorporating Ahmed's answer:

MessageService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private messagesPageSource = new Subject<number>();
    messagesPage$ = this.messagesPageSource.asObservable();

    public setPage(page: number)
    {
        this.messagesPageSource.next(page);
    }
}
```

MainComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from './messages.service';

@Component({
    selector: "main-component",
    template: `
        <div (scroll)="onContainerScrollEvent($event)">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
`
})
export class MainComponent {
    private pageNumber: number = 1;
    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
        messsageService.messagesPage$.subscribe(p => { });
    }

    onContainerScroll(event: any) {
        this.pageNumber += 1;
        this.messageService.setPage(this.pageNumber);
    }
}
```

messagesComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from './messages.service';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
    selector: "messages",
    templateUrl: "messages.view.html"
})
export class messagesComponent implements OnInit {
    private pageNumber: number = 1;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
        this.subscription = messageService.messagesPage$.subscribe(p => {
            this.pageNumber = p;
            this.getMessages();
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getMessages();
    }

    private getMessages() {
        //Call service to retrieve messages
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to inject `MainComponent` to `MessagesComponent` and then pass this component to `MainComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bi-directional service as described in the section `Parent and children communicate via a service` of this angular cookbook:

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Create a message service which you'll use to communicate between your parent and child component and any other component you want as well.

I'll skip providing a code example as the angular cookbook above has a pretty good example.

Comment: Ah cool! This is a very easy way to attach an eventlistener to a shared variable.